# PHP equivalent to OpenSSL RSA command

Tags: php, openssl, private-key

How could I remove passphase from RSA private key using PHP
I know that in OpenSSL it is this way: 
`openssl rsa -in key.key -out key.key` 
and I am searching equivalent command to this one in PHP.

---

RSA command requires the pass

```
OpenSSL> rsa -in key2.key -out key2.key 
Enter pass phrase for key2.key:
```

Comment: What about system? http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

Comment: I don't want to keep keys on server. Only one place where they appears are variables

Comment: Have you looked at [this openssl manual page](http://au1.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-export-to-file.php)?

Comment: This function saves private key generated by this function: `openssl_pkey_new`, providing passphase is required if pass was used while generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/):

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->setPassword('password');
$rsa->loadKey('...');

$rsa->setPassword();
echo $rsa->getPrivateKey();
?>
```

Comment: This is exactly what my answer does.

Comment: @Jack - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908284/removing-password-from-rsa-private-key and tell me why openssl_* isn't working.

Comment: So that's fixed now =D I suppose it's because `Crypt_RSA` writes those keys with a non-compatible line length ... which is really strange.

Comment: Yah - I think you're right. I sent the author an email. But I think it's just a matter of tolerances. PuTTY likes those keys just fine. I mean, what is the key but a base64-encoded DER? Why should the line length matter to OpenSSL? Why is a new line needed? I don't know how Disa got her keys. I was the first one to mention phpseclib - not her. So maybe other programs are creating keys that OpenSSL doesn't like either with it's uber pickyness.

Comment: @ansur Thanks for posting the follow up question though, it was worthwhile for both of us I think :)

Answer (score 2):

This would accomplish the same operation using the `openssl` extension:

```
$key = file_get_contents('key2.key');
$password = 'your password or pass phrase';

if (false === ($pkey = openssl_pkey_get_private($key, $password))) {
    die(openssl_error_string());
}
openssl_pkey_export($pkey, $out_key);
file_put_contents('key2.key', $out_key);
```

A concrete example:

```
$key = <<<EOS
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,775352C44A559B6C

V8EuwC29zy4yuY7Ie+HvyygjKJx4G+VF/SgjjCQR+Q/iLaXcoXhIMBmP9ugQpywu
Tgmg25PruaXl3Mabs2h03aUwLyFEEjcnaVz4IFYGflqDIBbSb/Y4Q9Ef0OjbCwCJ
5pEnD0ATPtb+bptHk7VitvyK9vIN4zrqDeWdpGkqhYZx4SkUDLBhcYYYA3eY8P7y
/yeUmHt2p12W7xF4OWflNj0ot7N2GoofKrAomW0vHVAAlVHj4OVyZYeOEG/8gm2A
a3xo+LS9D2tFJjCtnP5ytczWnsoe18bKlWbjV/IimlkVEqR6jx0jC99eCUHyaSvm
OfU/DHHcooBIJxXB5VfxFbRzjyWYgsAiVf2lThvusRb+j8/Ey28t5CWx8ME2hgmk
hrTPmCFor+Lx/7++cmOFWSNvJU8MrC6jH+q2R3xIPuY=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOS;
$password = 'superman';

if (false === ($pkey = openssl_pkey_get_private($key, $password))) {
    die(openssl_error_string());
}
openssl_pkey_export($pkey, $out_key);
echo $out_key;
```

Comment: This functions saves encrypted key

Comment: I have to save it decrypted

Comment: @Disa: And? What is your issue?

Comment: @Disa the third parameter to `openssl_pkey_export_to_file()` is the pass phrase, which i've left empty.

Comment: `$config = array('private_key_bits' => $k, 'passphrase' => "$p");
$privKey = openssl_pkey_new($config);
openssl_pkey_export($privKey, $klucz, "$p");`
in $p is passphase and $k is length. After generating this key I have to decrypt it

Comment: @Jack Leaving third paramenter empty will lead to parser error, because the key is encrypted

Comment: @Disa From your question it would seem that you have a key with pass phrase and you wish to remove it ... if that's not the case, please update your question.

Comment: @Jack Because it increases the security of key

Comment: @Jack Generating key without passphase makes it less secure, but the passpahse inside key makes another problem later. WWW Server will ask for this password everytime it starts up

Comment: It decreases the security level. Encrypted key, which is later decrypted offers way better security than not encrypted at generation.

Comment: @Disa: Why don't you create subkeys you can revoke? Wouldn't that be more secure?

Comment: @Disa I've just tested my code and it works exactly like how `openssl` works on the command line.