# Having trouble with openssl_x509_parse() function

Tags: php, openssl, certificate, x509

I'm having trouble with the openssl_x509_parse() function

```
$parsed_cert = openssl_x509_parse(file_get_contents('/home/my_location/aaa010101aaa__csd_01.cer'));
```

the function is returning a false and I'm unsure about the reasons. Maybe the certificate file must be in `.pem` or `.crt`?

EDIT: 
the code was ok, but the format of the file was the issue, so i had to transform it into a .crt from the .cer original.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the example from [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-parse.php), your code seems fine. Problem may be in file_get_contents.

Please try the following and check the if file is valid.

```
$file = file_get_contents('/home/my_location/aaa010101aaa__csd_01.cer');
$parsed_cert = openssl_x509_parse($file);
```

Now check what is file. Is it exists or a valid certificate file?

Answer (score 0):

[phpseclib's pure PHP X509 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/index.html) is more fault tolerant of X.509 certs than OpenSSL is. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');

$x509 = new File_X509();
$cert = $x509->loadX509('...'); // see google.crt

print_r($cert);
?>
```

As for OpenSSL's being less fault tolerant...  an example would be how [OpenSSL won't decode keys whose individual lines are longer than 64 bytes whereas phpseclib will](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13908986/569976).