# PHP openssl_public_encrypt “key parameter is not a valid key”

Tags: php, openssl, public-key

I have my public key in a file named , publickey.key 
and the content of that file is this,

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtixUGzGpLXgZ7AV1HfmIHV/FEF+fww77FekRc2oLhUOd4HitwCPo76fjtdsQBEt8w9HZ3CXVphaAU2BA6MEZJ3ShVMsdAXb2ZA1C+lu7k1GV9M/BhucTg35HujSK647Sc5MwVLwFsN80dAnGsZF8gwb2TNUzXHwzbAb30T01zuqf8RCM75OwKZFYqzu7FOVrtk/w9mh92MOXG0l7WSqNIctu8Kxka/tEJJIA5nqMGNMocjwprXy66NS7FFy1GY+NnxfFLtODqq0tllc50UCDsnqSvNmj2wcnAcsCzNOoxPPgp7t8S+sQvOzgc5W3CDjIsYEiGD+vzSVNkGiRou577wIDAQAB
```

/////// And in my .php file i am following below steps to encrypt my string using this public key

```
$fp=fopen ("publickey.key","r");
    $publicKey=fread($fp,8192);
    fclose($fp);
$encrypted = '';
$secret='what i want to encrypt';

    if (!openssl_public_encrypt($secret, $encrypted, $publicKey)) 
    {   
        die('Failed to encrypt data');
    }
```

but i am getting this error.

Warning: openssl_public_encrypt() [function.openssl-public-encrypt]: key parameter is not a valid public key in......

Is there some thing that i am doing wrong in my code?
Help Please!

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` before and after the key blob. And you might need to use chunk_split, too, because [OpenSSL is pretty picky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13908986/569976).

Really, though, I'd recommend using [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/intro.html). It has much more versatile key handling, among other things.