# openssl_pkey_get_private returns string ''

Tags: php, openssl, rsa

Recently I use openssl generate RSA Private Key to encrypted my data.

```
    $private_key = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIICXQIBAAKBgQDGCn4a42xSG6Hs0h+BSWG/MQmXOpIqd6ptlfFxMFQeL9bvJ9jR j0842NyaWIAedxQrv/0+XC5pYF8ExrcGXCnWtCpUTK2M6cgkTLgkkptLz5N+z8jd AeSbakKkJuQEgEyKI1cIrjRhz6u6yfjoPKZAmVdlwEDN1u4TweZ1HDDxHQIDAQAB AoGANPgvfI+htGBxsf8NsC3peBLspsdiuvsg2YjGeGjdxukyyurUglCbdvACKUJM mlltSrpiSOCtBUBiicuAvrG9+pdjQb1gPui/xj83ZbNytfG6K8UFk6cokH6fEgON Pd3npWlhXwdrJUxcFLzlJzREq18VyAWwgsbH82//ineOF6ECQQD3HOpE+IQ2JDIL Kxna/rVnW5RSvImddKksC4KLk7IsMFqsfo+e/Vkf3D7vmsMDCXCNpt5+ttLF93lU 3Iz1j/bJAkEAzSnJ4kp9rsvf7X5OqLWOJjR6CDGK3RSwSXeSMoJSIvV6rSXXQryU ltiYct5A5Oi3g49cOYNuYMt1bw3uTEVNtQJBAKqR7e8fr3sDrvtgi99LE4I9h3s4 orDp1uANLdYUY9b2pZANaCtxavR//X08UUGmYWeVeFz06zY05S47cp0J+2kCQEyk CbixHxZHLtWnU3cOq5V2EQgyia9g5SHsuv6HVGuezD8WXb2eeNuI+hofEJrynGtX CJqrkHY0SyA7UgPH9+kCQQDRrxJ4plB0nWqhLpdc3OV74vW0m11LS8+270nMMVN1 IP08iRfF4ASWEXoe5A2LNEP4ydFw68Ve08WaRwSJ65kn -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

    $pi_key =  openssl_pkey_get_private($private_key);
    var_dump($pikey."\n");
```

return:

```
string(1) "
"
```

I use it at my local wampserver,But I get return data is resource.

```
string(16) "Resource id #46
"
```

My openssl version:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL is [pretty picky when it comes to keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13908986/569976). All that base64-encoded data needs to span multiple lines, each of which is, at most, 64 lines long. I used [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) to convert you key and it worked fine for me after the conversion (whereas it didn't before):

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$key = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIICXQIBAAKBgQDGCn4a42xSG6Hs0h+BSWG/MQmXOpIqd6ptlfFxMFQeL9bvJ9jR j0842NyaWIAedxQrv/0+XC5pYF8ExrcGXCnWtCpUTK2M6cgkTLgkkptLz5N+z8jd AeSbakKkJuQEgEyKI1cIrjRhz6u6yfjoPKZAmVdlwEDN1u4TweZ1HDDxHQIDAQAB AoGANPgvfI+htGBxsf8NsC3peBLspsdiuvsg2YjGeGjdxukyyurUglCbdvACKUJM mlltSrpiSOCtBUBiicuAvrG9+pdjQb1gPui/xj83ZbNytfG6K8UFk6cokH6fEgON Pd3npWlhXwdrJUxcFLzlJzREq18VyAWwgsbH82//ineOF6ECQQD3HOpE+IQ2JDIL Kxna/rVnW5RSvImddKksC4KLk7IsMFqsfo+e/Vkf3D7vmsMDCXCNpt5+ttLF93lU 3Iz1j/bJAkEAzSnJ4kp9rsvf7X5OqLWOJjR6CDGK3RSwSXeSMoJSIvV6rSXXQryU ltiYct5A5Oi3g49cOYNuYMt1bw3uTEVNtQJBAKqR7e8fr3sDrvtgi99LE4I9h3s4 orDp1uANLdYUY9b2pZANaCtxavR//X08UUGmYWeVeFz06zY05S47cp0J+2kCQEyk CbixHxZHLtWnU3cOq5V2EQgyia9g5SHsuv6HVGuezD8WXb2eeNuI+hofEJrynGtX CJqrkHY0SyA7UgPH9+kCQQDRrxJ4plB0nWqhLpdc3OV74vW0m11LS8+270nMMVN1 IP08iRfF4ASWEXoe5A2LNEP4ydFw68Ve08WaRwSJ65kn -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';

$pi_key = openssl_pkey_get_private($key);

var_dump($pi_key);

echo "\r\n";

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($key);

$pi_key =  openssl_pkey_get_private($rsa);
var_dump($pi_key);

echo "\r\n";
```

The first one output `bool(false)` and the second one returned `resource(8) of type (OpenSSL key)`.